# How to wire AC control signal wire to compressor?

Tags: hvac

My AC indoors is from one company and outdoors is from another company. The problem is that indoors has CP wire, which is responsible for sending signals to a compressor to switch it off and on.

My compressor only has 3 slots: phase, neutral and ground, which is an old model type. So how do I connect it? Do I connect phase to phase, neutral to neutral, ground to ground AC? The compressor is running all the time. Any idea what can be done ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the exact brand & model of each of the units involved. Without that information, your guess is as good as ours, and either is likely to kill the units or, possibly, you.

Comment: I would use that wire to control a relay, or contactor.

Comment: What make and model are the AC units in question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine where your compressor is fed from. If it's fed directly from your main panel, then you need a contactor  switch, relay, in your compressor unit to attach those signal wires to. If your compressor is fed from your inside unit, rarely done, then your contactor should be in there with large wires going from the contactor out to the compressor unit. Those signal wires should go to the contactor.

Comment: "My AC indoors is from one company and outdoors is from another company". Perhaps the outdoor unit is designed to be fed from a contactor in the indoor unit, which it doesn't have because it's a mismatched type. So that leaves the solution as "install an appropriate contactor"

Comment: @user253751  Definitely a possibility or maybe it's there and wired incorrectly.